# Broadcasting global events without $broadcast in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This question has been googled by me. I wasn't able to find a solution so that's the reason i ask it here.

The provided solution must respect the rules that are defined by the core team so don't suggest alternatives cause there is no way i can change those rules.

I wrote a directive, that can communicate with the other instances via $rootScope.$broadcast. Now appearently i am not allowed to use rootScope and $broadcast. I have to use a service instead.

My question is, do services capacity to broadcast an event globally that can be received by the instances of the directive and how?

Comment: You can raise a $broadcast from everywhere, but yeah where is your code?

Comment: You can consider the most simple directive example of AngularJS as my code and explain on that. I need to use a seperated service for that and not the $broadcast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make service from code like this
http://www.abidibo.net/blog/2014/01/16/javascript-event-dispatcher/

Then you simple use service's `register` and `emit` methods to communicate between components.

Comment: Thanks. I am not using Vanilla but already came up with a similar solution.